# Run a command on connection success mysql

Tags: go, mysql-connector

How do i set a mysql session variable on each connection created to the db.

```sql
set AURORA_READ_REPLICA='session'
```

Comment: I don't want to set the flag on every sql command request. Ideally, a connection hook would be great but i don't see such a thing in database/sql code

Answer (score 0):

The system variable can be passed in the connection URL. For more details, please refer to this [link](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/db#system-variables)

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:mysql@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/dbname?tls=skip-verify")
```

If AURORA_READ_REPLICA is supported by MySQL Server, pass like this

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:mysql@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/db?AURORA_READ_REPLICA=%27session%27")
```

Comment: It doesn't let you set the variable this way